# How to scroll in another window without switching to it?

Tags: vim-windows, scrolling

There is a keybinding in Emacs that lets you scroll in another window that you're not currently working on (`C-M-v` to *scroll-other-window-down* and `C-M-V` to *scroll-other-window-up*). For example, in a horizontal split, while you're writing in the upper window, you can scroll the view of the bottom window without switching to that window. I'm curious whether there is a similar keybinding for that in Vim or if it's not natively there, how can we add a similar feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> scroll the view of the bottom window without switching to that window

Something like this

```
call win_execute(win_getid(winnr('j')), "normal! \<C-E>")
```

`winnr('j')` returns Window number of a window below the current one. `win_getid()` translates Window number to `:h winid`. Then `win_execute()` runs an arbitrary command as if that window were active (but display is not updated, and auto-commands are not triggered).

Note: `win_execute()` is not available in Neovim.

Comment: This answer is very educational and useful. I just wonder how can I modify `win_getid(winner('j'))` to tell him to do something on the **other** window assuming there are only two. The other window could be on the right, left, up, or down. Can I generalize it like that?

Comment: From `:h winnr()`, I can see you can  use `#` (last window used) in place of `j`.

Comment: @Biggybi I saw that, too. But _the last window_ is not always _the other window_ in the same tab. I might switch between tabs and I guess using this command would not point me to the other window in the same tab but the window back in the tab I switched from.

Comment: @Biggybi My bad! You're 100% right. I just checked out that command in action and it works right, even if I just switch from another window in another tab. Looks like tabs are separate environments in Vim.

Comment: @SaeedAhadian There are "window IDs" and "window numbers". Both are used here. Window ID is a unique number for a whole Vim session (1000+); while "window number" is basically "a window position within tab" (1, 2, 3 etc.).

Answer (score 5):

I use the mouse for this. With `set mouse=a` I can scroll any open window from any mode (including normal mode). It’s not the purest solution, but it works very well for me.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have 2 windows. Then map like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
map <F11> <C-W><C-W><C-D><C-W><C-W>
```

It will map <kbd>F11</kbd> to do these actions:

1. `<C-W><C-W>` - move cursor to second window.
2. `<C-D>` - scroll second window downwards half of screen.
3. `<C-W><C-W>` - move cursor back to first window.

Change part 2 to whatever you want, look at `:h scroll.txt` to see more commands. For example, `<C-U>` scrolls half screen upward. `<C-E>`, `<C-Y>` scroll one line.

See:

```
:h CTRL-W_CTRL-W  
:h windows.txt  
:h scroll.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
nnoremap <M-PageDown> <C-w>p<C-d><C-w>p
nnoremap <M-PageUp> <C-w>p<C-u><C-w>p
```

I use this in Neovim.